# Converting arithmetic formula from string to a values

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, user-defined-functions

I have a table in which all entries are in form of arithmetic formulas (i.e. '0.51 + 2.50 + 3.50').

In this table all columns are of type varchar. The table has many columns like this.

I want to calculate formula within a function and use it for some other calculation, but my problem is "EXEC" can not be used in side function and i can not take function within Stored procedure.

So, Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Only ` + `? Or entire spectrum (+,-,*,/) ...

Comment: it could be any thing (+,-,*,/)

Comment: And you want also operator precedence working as it should (2+2*2 = 6 not 8) yes? Show more expression, do you need Math functions, brackets, ^ for power, ...

Comment: Edit your question, show more samples, I could write code in T-SQL for simple cases, but I won't because then you will write that you have to handle etc. Probably the easiest way is to write CLR func that will evaluate your Math expression

Comment: I just wanna know is there any feasible approach, rest all here and there will handle.

Comment: Write [custom CLR function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: So, you are saying to write some CLR in C# or VB, and use dll in function ??

Comment: Yup, you pass to function string, and your CLR function does Math expression evaluation(you could copy code from internet) and return double.

Comment: okies, thanks but do you have any sample for this??? May which you can post as an solution for me

Comment: Example http://ncalc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval SQL.NET](http://eval-sql.net/)

Instead to create your own SQL CLR as suggested, you can use an existing one which allow you to esily write C# syntax in T-SQL.

```
-- SELECT 6.51
SELECT SQLNET::New('0.51 + 2.50 + 3.50').Eval()
```

You can even use column as formula and parameter

```
-- Evaluate dynamically expression in T-SQL
DECLARE @tableFormula TABLE (
   Formula VARCHAR(255), X INT, Y INT, Z INT
)

INSERT  INTO @tableFormula VALUES ('x+y*z', 1, 2, 3 ), 
                                  ('(x+y)*z', 1, 2, 3 )
-- SELECT 7
-- SELECT 9
SELECT SQLNET::New(Formula)
              .Val('x', X)
              .Val('y', Y)
              .Val('z', Z).EvalInt()
FROM @tableFormula
```

Documentation: [Dynamically evaluating arithmetic operation in T-SQL](http://eval-sql.net/arithmetic-expressions)